# Proxmox API Powershell Hashtable Arguments

Tags: powershell, proxmox

I´m trying to use a pPowershell [module](https://github.com/Corsinvest/cv4pve-api-powershell)  to communicate with the Proxmox-API. It worked fine until I tried to pass an `<Hashtable>` argument.

```
foreach($mac in $passed_MACs){
    $networkConfig = @{
        1 = @{
            model = 'e1000';
            bridge = 'vmbr0';
            macaddr = $mac;
        };
    }

    $storageConfig = @{
        1 = 'local-lvm:32';
    }

    $bootableIso = @{
        1 = 'local:iso/ubuntu.iso'
    }

    $nextId = Get-PveClusterNextid

    $createVM = New-PveNodesQemu -Node $node -Vmid $nextId.Response.data -Memory 2048 -ScsiN $storageConfig -IdeN $bootableIso -NetN $networkConfig
    
    $createVM | Out-File -FilePath .\test.txt -Append
    $createVM.Parameters | Out-File -FilePath .\test.txt -Append
}
```

The response is:

```
Response            : 
StatusCode          : 400
ReasonPhrase        : Parameter verification failed.
IsSuccessStatusCode : False
RequestResource     : /nodes/dvl/qemu
Parameters          : {[scsi1, local-lvm:32], [memory, 2048], [ide1, local:iso/ubuntu.iso], [vmid, 100]…}
Method              : Post
ResponseType        : json


Name                           Value
----                           -----
scsi1                          local-lvm:32
memory                         2048
ide1                           local:iso/ubuntu.iso
vmid                           100
net1                           {[macaddr, bc-54-a1-60-2c-25], [bridge, vmbr0], [model, e1000]}
```

The problem lies in the $networkConfig since without it it works. The other variant I tried was this
`$networkConfig = @{ 1 = 'model=e1000,bridge=vmbr0,macaddr=' + $mac;    }`

The [documentation](https://raw.githack.com/Corsinvest/cv4pve-api-powershell/master/doc/index.html#New-PveNodesQemu)  does not contain any example

Comment: I'm not sure if that function can take a Hashtable within a Hashtable. Can you try `$networkConfig = @{model = 'e1000'; bridge = 'vmbr0'; macaddr = $mac }` ?

Comment: It looks like that module uses ```Write-Debug``` to report additional info - if you add ```$DebugPreference = “Continue”``` to your script you might get additional info about what http request is actually being sent and that might give a clue about what your ```$networkConfig``` variable should contain…

Comment: So after a quick play with the PS module, it looks like your code is generating a url like ```https://:/api2/json/nodes/aaa/qemu?memory=2048&scsi1=local-lvm:32&ide1=local:iso/ubuntu.iso&net1=System.Collections.Hashtable&vmid=100``` - note ```net1=System.Collections.Hashtable``` in the querystring. I can't find any examples in the documentation but at a guess you could try ```$networkConfig = @{ 1 = "model=e1000,bridge=vmbr0,macaddr=$mac" }``` which generates ```net1=model=e1000,bridge=vmbr0,macaddr=00000000000000``` instead...

Comment: @Theo still nothing, but I belive the function must take a Hashtable within a Hashtable, because the Variables macaddr, bridge and model are not within net1.  `ide1   local:iso/ubuntu.install.iso`  
`netmacaddr  bc-24-11-60-2c-22`  
`netmodel    e1000`

Comment: @mclayton It didn´t work but I think it´s pretty close, since the passed parameter net1 is not `{[macaddr, 00000000000000], [bridge, vmbr0], [model, e1000]}` but `model=e1000,bridge=vmbr0,macaddr=00000000000000`  I thought it might be the format of the MAC, so I removed it since it´s optional, but still not working

Comment: @mclayton Thank you for the `$DebugPreference = 'Continue'` hint. Since I can now see the output, I might fix it.

Comment: @mclayton so I found a solution, insted of `$networkConfig = @{ 1 = "model=e1000,bridge=vmbr0,macaddr=$mac" }` I used `$networkConfig = @{ 1 = "model%3Dvirtio%2Cbridge%3Dvmbr0%2Cmacaddr%3D$mac"}` That means the Module maybe dosn´t escape the strings or maybe there is a different approach. Anyways thank you! How can I mark a comment as a solution?

Comment: You can’t mark a comment as an answer - my comments were really only troubleshooting steps anyway. I think there’s a restriction on new users answering their own questions (you need 15 reputation) but as soon as you hit that you can come back and post your own answer… (I also just upvoted your question so that should get you nearer to being able to do that :-).)

Comment: Also, you could think about posting an issue in the ps module’s GitHub repo to suggest adding logic to convert hashtables into the appropriate querystring values - it seems like that would be useful functionality to have in the module.

Comment: Yes will do, great idea